# Problem with unicode character

Tags: fonts, unicode

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and desktop. The character "u2B80" ⮀ is not shown in my desktop pc. I don't have any clue about this. I'm using the same fonts (The same Monaco font and Monospace) and the locale info is the same:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8  
LC_ALL=
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

U+2B80 does not denote any character; it is an unassigned code point, aka. reserved code point. This means that no character has been assigned to it, but such an assignment may be made in a future version of Unicode. Therefore, it should not be used be used in character data at all, not even by private agreements.

If a font contains a glyph allocated to that code point, the font should be considered as broken or as experimental.